# reversing a string in C bad output

Tags: c, string, size, puts

I have a weird bug with the length of my strings. I'm fairly new at this so it's probably something basic I am missing out.

I'm trying to write a program that gets a pointer to an array of characters (IE first character of the string) and it returns a pointer to a string of the same size as the first one, but the letters are reversed. For example Computer will become retupmoC. tacocat will stay tacocat :)

here's the code:

```
char* return_flipped_string(char* stringptr)
{
    int i=0,size_of_string=length_of_string(stringptr);
    char *flipped;
    flipped=(char *)malloc(size_of_string*sizeof(char));
    while(i<size_of_string)
    {
        *(flipped+i)=*(stringptr+size_of_string-1-i);
        i++;
    }
    return flipped;
}
```

stringptr is a pointer to the original string, flipped is the one i am returning. 
when I print the flipped string, it shows the original one flipped, followed by indistinguishable gibberish. They are not the same size for some reason.

here's the code I wrote for finding the length of a string (working properly)

```
int length_of_string(char* stringptr)
{
    int length=0,i=0;
    while(*(stringptr+i)!='\0')
    {
        length++;
        i++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: tip: `i` and `length` in your length function are going to be identical, so might as well just use `i` only.

Comment: Any particular reason you've written length_of_string rather than just using the standard strlen() function?

Comment: @MarcB: correct, I haven't noticed that. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @NigelHarper: As I said in the comment below, strlen gets a const char array, and I want to work with pointers only.

Comment: @OriaGruber: the prototype for `strlen` is `size_t strlen(const char*)` so it most certainly takes a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `NUL` terminating character.  You need to allocate **one additional character** for `flipped` and add a `'\0'` at the end explicitly.

```
char* return_flipped_string(char* stringptr)
{
    int i=0,size_of_string=length_of_string(stringptr);
    char *flipped;
    flipped=(char *)malloc((size_of_string + 1)*sizeof(char));
    while(i<size_of_string)
    {
        *(flipped+i)=*(stringptr+size_of_string-1-i);
        i++;
    }
    *(flipped+1) = '\0';
    return flipped;
}
```

BTW - you are aware of the `strlen` function in the Standard Library right?  Your `length_of_string` function duplicates it.  I can't remember if `strrev` is in the ANSI/ISO Standard or not.

Comment: I tried using strlen but it recieves as an argument a const char. And I want to work with pointers only. So either I used strlen incorrectly, or it just doesn't fit here. I would love a clarification.

Comment: The parameter to `strlen` is a "pointer to a `const char`" so `strlen("12345678") == 8`.  You can replace `length_of_string` with `strlen` as long as you include `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to append a null byte ('\0') to the end of the flipped string. The length of the flipped string data buffer is the length of the input string **plus one** for the null string terminator byte. It's that null byte that tells where the string ends.

Answer (score 3):

you need to NULL terminate the string.... like so..

```
  while(i<size_of_string)
    {
        *(flipped+i)=*(stringptr+size_of_string-1-i);
        i++;
    }
    flipped[size_of_string]=0;
    return flipped;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a string in C.  C has character (`char`) arrays, which are *interpretted* (by convention) as strings when they contain a `NUL`  character (`'\0'`).  The first `NUL` found terminates the string.  If your array does not include a `NUL`, then any of the standard string functions will keep on reading the buffer beginning at the address that you provided until they encounter a null byte.

Hence the gibberish.